# Disiamylborane on alkyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am having problem predicting the last product in the following reaction:

> $$\ce{CH#CH ->[Na/NH3 (l)][(Excess)] (P) ->[DCl] (Q) ->[(i)Sia2BH][(ii)CH3COOH] (R)}$$

I am getting an alkyl chloride as product $\ce{Q}$ and cannot understand how it will react with $\ce{Sia2BH}$. Or, I think I am doing some mistake in the formation of product $\ce{P}$. I do know that alkynes on reaction with $\ce{Na/NH3}$ shall give *trans* alkene (Birch reduction). Will the "excess" part affect the reaction differently?

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CH#CH &->[Na/NH3 (l)][(Excess)] CH2=CH2} &(\ce{P}) \tag{1} \\
\ce{CH2=CH2 &->[DCl] CH2D-CH2Cl} &(\ce{Q}) \tag{2} \\
\ce{CH2D-CH2Cl &->[(i)Sia2BH][(ii)CH3COOH] ?} &(\ce{Q}) \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think the DCl step is the work up of the sodium/NH3 reduction step and will give the deuterated alkene

Comment: That's quite an unclear question. It's more common for workup after every step to be assumed / implicit, and based on that your interpretation would be correct. But @Waylander's interpretation is the only one that makes step 3 sensible.

Comment: so the product P will be NaC≡CNa, and Q will be DC≡CD, and then Q as CHD=CHD?

Comment: I did read today that Acetylene reacts with sodium in liq Ammonia or Sodamide to form sodium acetylides. I guess, NaC≡CNa shall be formed and the end product will be what @Waylander said.